# Chrome DevTools in Selenium c# without specific version

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

For a project I am using the Network logger in Selenium DevTools to do make analysis easier during testing. Unfortunately I have to specify the version of chrome in the usings, which would not have been a problem except that my IT department updates chrome. This results in mismatches between the DevTools version and the chrome version, breaking the test.

Is there a way to not use this specific version, that when chrome updates my tests don't break immediately.

A part of my code:

```
using DevToolsSessionDomains = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V122.DevToolsSessionDomains;

public class ChromeBrowser : MyBrowser
{
private static readonly ILogger _log = Serilog.Log.ForContext<ChromeBrowser>();
private ChromeDriver driver;

public override void InitDriver(bool runHeadless)
{
    new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig(), VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser);
    var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

    driver = new ChromeDriver(service, DriverOptions(runHeadless), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
    pid = service.ProcessId;
    _log.Information($"ChromeDriver PID = {pid}");
    _log.Information($"Chrome capabilities: {driver.Capabilities}");

    EnableLogging();
}
public void EnableLogging()
{
    if (!Properties.NetworkLogger)
    {
        //No logger is enabled
        _log.Information("No logging of network activity will be done during this test run.");
        return;
    }

    driver.ExecuteCdpCommand("Network.enable", new Dictionary<string, object>());

    var session = driver.GetDevToolsSession();
    var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();

    domains.Network.Enable(new EnableCommandSettings());
    _log.Information("Logging of network activity has started.");
    domains.Network.RequestWillBeSent += RequestSentHandler;
    domains.Network.ResponseReceived += ResponseReceivedHandler;
}

public static void ResponseReceivedHandler(object sender, ResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //logging responses given
    if (MimeTypes.ExcludedFromLogs.Exists(m => e.Response.MimeType.Contains(m)))
    {
        return;
    }
    
    string logLine = $"Status: {e.Response.Status}\tType: {e.Response.MimeType}\tUrl: {e.Response.Url}";

    if (!MimeTypes.ExcludedFromBodyLogs.Exists(m => e.Response.MimeType.Contains(m)))
    {
        LogMessageBody(e.RequestId);
    }

    if (e.Response.Status != 200)
    {
        _log.Warning(logLine);
    }
    else
    {
        _log.Information(logLine);
    }
}

private static void LogMessageBody(string requestId)
{        
    var chromeDriver = TestBrowser.Browser as ChromeDriver;
    var session = chromeDriver.GetDevToolsSession();
    var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();

    var settings = new GetResponseBodyCommandSettings
    {
        RequestId = requestId
    };

    var command = domains.Network.GetResponseBody(settings);
    if (command.IsCompletedSuccessfully) {
        var body = command.Result;
        if (body != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(body.Body))
        {
            _log.Information($"Body for requestId {requestId}");
            _log.Information(body.Body);
        }
    }
}


public static void RequestSentHandler(object sender, RequestWillBeSentEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.Request.HasPostData ?? false))
    {
        return;
    }
    //logging requests made
    string logLine = $"Method: {e.Request.Method}\tRequest sent:{e.Request.PostData}";
    _log.Information(logLine);
}
}
```

Stack: Selenium4, .net6

Comment: Are you using Selenium in the context of testing an application or web scraping? Is this being run in a test project in Visual Studio, a console application, and forms application?

Comment: Is there something specific about the V122  class that cannot be substituted with the `OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.DevToolsSessionDomains` abstract class?

Comment: You might need to [edit] your question to show us more code. Its hard to see what to change, since it is just a short snippet.

Comment: There is nothing specific in the v122 except that this is my current version of the Chrome browser, as soon as it updates I need to update the using. Unfortunately the abstract class does not have the Network class in it.
The content of the snippet should entail the essence of the script, but I'll update it with some more context.

Comment: I'd suggest trying Playwright, [record a trace](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-tracing) and use the [Trace Viewer](https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer) to check not just network requests but the actual DOM elements at various points.

Comment: As a side note, if you are using the latest version of Selenium, you shouldn't need WebDriverManager anymore.

Comment: Thanks @GregBurghardt, I'll try to get rid of that extra dependency ;)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos unfortunately I can only get this issue when I use the pipeline run (for the first time). On my local machine I do not have this issue, so recording is unfortunately not possible. I was able to do a wireshark recording, but need a colleague for interpretation

Comment: My comment was to replace Selenium with Playwright so you don't have to depend on Dev Tools at all. In any case, what do you mean by "pipeline run"? Running on a CI server? That's important information that should be not just a tag but part of the title. `for the first time` means that the initial CI environment is missing something that's installed during the first run - perhaps Chrome is in the process of getting updated, or the wrong ChromeDriver is used. The fact you don't get the same error the second time means the CI environment isn't fully reset too.